# In ColdFusion How to Eliminate Vulnerable for Cross-Site Script

Tags: security, coldfusion

What is the best way to stop Cross-Site Scripting for ColdFusion?

Is there a setting to set in the CF Admin or is their code in you can put in Application.cfc?

**Example Code:**

```
http://test.com/file.cfm?center=fisCenter')" onmouseover="alert('Insert Hax Here.')" style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:10000px;height:10000px;z-index:100">
```

Comment: Yea, don't insert unsanitized content into html as html. There's a method specific for dealing with html attributes and inputs, but they're not the only place where this happens.

Comment: This is the URL coming code coming in from a person typing it in.  So I am trying to find out how to fix this.

Comment: Right. and before you insert that back into html that you're serving to users you should be sanitizing it. There is an admin setting in railo (and likely acf) that can do basic testing of url and form scopes, but i doubt it would catch everything. It certainly wouldn't help anything already in the system being pulled from a database or 3rd party for example.

Comment: I am not serving this back to you user so I am trying to find out how in ColdFusion to stop this.  That is the question... so if you don't know the answer let someone who knows ColdFusion tell me.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're not serving it back to the users... there's no cross-site scripting risk.

Comment: I have used the first couple of strip functions here to remove some of the naughty code:  http://cflib.org/search?search=strip  StripAllBut  I have also used http://cflib.org/udf/stripHTML  before.  Not quite sure though how they would work with your example.  Maybe you could take one of the functions and alter it a bit to do what you need.

Comment: Consider using `getSafeHTML()` function. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getsafehtml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the answer I was looking for so far.

```
<!--- In Application.cfc --->
<cfscript>
  this.scriptprotect = "all";   
</cfscript>


<!--- In OnRequestStart in Application.cfc --->
<cfscript>
  sanitizeScope(url);   
</cfscript>

<!--- CF10 Canonicalize --->
<cfscript>
/* This function decodes any particular scope values */
public void function sanitizeScope( struct scope ) 
  {
    for( var key in scope ) 
    {
      scope[key] = canonicalize(scope[key], false, false);
    }
  } 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: The sanitizeScope() function will try to canonicalize the scope[key], but the false,false means it won't restrict multi- or mixed- encoding. This will allow the function to proceed without failing, but there is little to no reason for a legitimate user to even try to pass multi- or mixed-encoded values through any of your scopes. I would say that's most likely a malicious user and should be booted and banned from your application asap.

Comment: You need to sanitize any user input, so run this on the form scope for any HTTP POST requests too. In the case that you have any screens where you're looping over the keys in the FORM or URL scope to output content on the screen, you need to sanitize the actual key names too.

Comment: This is to satisfy a test by a securiity team. There is no way for them to input this info on this current app.  I agree if someone posted that then they would have to do it manually.  I did not come up with the test just need to pass it.

Answer (score 4):

First things first: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet. OWASP has *tons* of resources to help devs better understand the problem. XSS isn't a CF problem, but a webdev problem.

That said, which version of CF are you working with? It's more difficult to deal with in CF9 or lower. Those versions have limited built-in functionality and may require falling back into Java methods, if able. But CF10 added a bunch of functionality.

`HTTPOnly Cookies` - while "available" well before CF10, CF10 added it as a setting in CF Administrator or by using `this.sessioncookie.httponly=true` in Application.cfc. You can still accomplish this in older versions through JVM settings or content headers. (https://www.petefreitag.com/item/764.cfm)

`Content Secruity Policy` - (https://content-security-policy.com/) I will admit that I'm not as familiar with CSP as I should be. It's not really CF, but it's still something to know about. It lets you establish the approved origin of the content in your site, which should hopefully prevent someone from injecting content that redirects a user's action to somewhere else. But be warned that it is browser-dependent.

`scriptProtect` is a CF Admin or Application.cfc setting. (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d69.html) will help with a lot of XSS, but not all. It's a simple pattern-matching blacklist method instead of a whitelist (it pretty much looks only for object, embed, script, applet, and meta), so there are many ways to get around it. It should be used but not relied upon or expected to be 100% safe.

`encodeFor*()` - (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforhtml.html). These have been much improved since the HTMLEditFormat() days. Make sure you use the appropriate encoding method.

`Canonicalize()` - (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/Canonicalize.html) This function is great, but I believe there was a minor change between 10 and 11 that adds a little better handling. With the additional CF11 throwOnError flag, when you check for both multi- and mixed encoding, you can throw/catch an error if either are detected and log/block that user. There is pretty much no reason any legitimate user would ever hit those flags, so logging/blocking isn't a bad idea.

Also see Dave Epler's excellent writeup in http://learncfinaweek.com/week1/Cross_Site_Scripting__XSS_/. That will give you some good info on XSS in ColdFusion.

And finally, as you can see from some of my earlier links, Pete Freitag has some the best security resources I've found (https://www.petefreitag.com), and he tends to be the expert I trust for information about ColdFusion application security. Pete's Bank of Insecurity app (https://github.com/foundeo/cfml-security-training) will give you some great examples of how CF can be exploited.

The moral of my story is one of basic Defense In Depth, even for a single type of exploit. Some of my examples above involve code you write, some are page headers (not quite the same kind of code) and some are Server Administrator functions or settings. You can never be 100% safe, but it's a good idea to throw multiple roadblocks up in the way of a malicious user.