# Coldfusion fileUpload a cfDocument

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, cfml

I create a pdf using cfDocument and I am trying to upload it to my server using fileUpload, but it is giving the error: `ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings.`

Here is my code:

```
// Create PDF
formPdf = "";
cfDocument(format="PDF", name="formPdf") { writeOutput(formContent); };

// Upload the PDF
destination = expandPath("./MyFolder/#ID#/");
if(!directoryExists(destination)){
    directoryCreate(destination);
}
fileUpload( destination, formPdf, "*.", "MakeUnique" );
```

Does fileUpload() just work with string? How can I upload a PDF file that I just created?

Thanks

Comment: Use something like `cfDocument(format="PDF", filename="#filepath#/formPdf.pdf")`. But since, I'm guessing, this information comes from a FORM, make sure to _validate_ the form data before you write a PDF and save it to your server.

Comment: (Edit) Wrong function. FileUpload() is for handling files transferred FROM a client browser to the server. You're already on the server, so no uploading involved.
To save the pdf to disk, try using cfdocument's "filename" attribute instead of using "name" (i.e. saving to a variable). From [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html) *"..Pathname of a file to contain the PDF or FlashPaper output...."* Technically, you could also use FileWrite(), but it's probably not necessary in this case.

Comment: And OT, it makes me happy to see another example of ColdFusion in cfscript instead of tags. :-)

Comment: Thank you Shawn. It works like a champ. If you want to post your answer, I can select it as solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you are asking, there's no need to upload a file since it's already on your server, and `cfdocument` can handle generating and saving a PDF file.

Refer to https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html for more info about `cfdocument`. `cfdocument` is designed to create a PDF out of formatted input.

You want the `filename` attribute of `cfdocument`. This defines the path name of the file that will contain the output.

You'll want something like:

```
destination = expandPath("./MyFolder/#ID#/");
if(!directoryExists(destination)){
    directoryCreate(destination); 
}

pdfName = "calculatedPDFName.pdf" ;

// Create PDF 
cfdocument(format="PDF", filename="#destination#/#pdfName#") {
    writeOutput( sanitizeMe(formContent) ) ;   
};
```

I included `sanitizeMe()` as a reminder to clean any form input before you use it or serve it back up, or *ESPECIALLY* before you save it back to the file system. That doesn't do anything, but something there should. There are about a bazillion discussions around the interwebs about how and why to do this.

*NOTE: I was going to link a couple of pages that talked about XSS and other injection issues, and the first link that popped up was one to SO. [In ColdFusion How to Eliminate Vulnerable for Cross-Site Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597947/in-coldfusion-how-to-eliminate-vulnerable-for-cross-site-script) When I looked down at the answer, I realized it was one of mine from last year. Gotta love when that happens. :-)*